# How to filter my nearby location by passing current location , radius and lat lon of near by locations

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

Input :

1. Current location lat lon
2. radius
3. list of near by lat lon

Required Output:

> List of lat lon which come under the provided radius from my current location.

Can someone give me the method to achieve it?

I have following code to check whether the passed locations come under the passed radius... How can we optimize more?
I don't was to use for loop to check my all locations everytime

```
public static boolean pointIsInCircle(PointF pointForCheck, PointF center,
        double radius) {
    if (getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(pointForCheck, center) <= radius)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public static double getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(PointF p1, PointF p2) {
    double R = 6371000; // m
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(p2.x - p1.x);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(p2.y - p1.y);
    double lat1 = Math.toRadians(p1.x);
    double lat2 = Math.toRadians(p2.x);

    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = R * c;

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Where is your effort in coding or search SO so far?

Comment: @Smutje I have submitted the code also. can you please give some solution and remove your down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Geo-Fence](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html) . *geo-fence* is a virtual perimeter for a real-world geographic area. A *geo-fence* could be dynamically generated—as in a radius around a store or point location. Or a *geo-fence* can be a predefined set of boundaries, like school attendance zones or neighborhood boundaries. Custom-digitized *geofences* are also in use.

Follow the link  [simple example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps).
 When the location-aware device of a location-based service (LBS) user enters or exits a *geo-fence,* the device receives a generated notification. This notification might contain information about the location of the device.

*Geofencing*, used with child location services, can notify parents if a child leaves a designated area.[

Comment: thanks but I am looking for something else

Answer (score 2):

lookslike you want to get nearby place so you can goto:**https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests**
feel free to ask any doubts you get while implementing this